# Using Jest with gRPC-Web

Tags: typescript, jestjs, create-react-app, grpc, grpc-web

We are using gRPC-Web client in our project, but when we try to run unit tests on code that imports generated gRPC classes we get an error

> TypeError: cannot read property 'navigator' of undefined.

I guess the problem is somehow related to the way generated modules are exposed, however I cannot figure out how to make it work with Jest.

I tried to mock `global.navigator` object manually using `setupTests.js` file, but it didn't help. It looks like the gRPC code is being executed before Jest.

Our web project is created using **Create React App** library with TypeScript without ejecting and we use default Jest configuration to run unit tests.

Please advise.

Comment: Provide the code you want to test

Comment: I am not sure where this "navigator" property comes from. Not from our grpc-web library. Can you provide more info?

Comment: After a couple of days struggling with this, I found what the problem was. By default Jest has `--transformIgnorePatterns /node_modules/` option which was overridden in our project. As a result our grpc api package wasn't correctly wrapped with Jest. After restoring this option to include all the contents of node_modules folder the problem disappeared.